# How to show Google map in background of a website

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to show Google map in background of a website?
For your reference, please see the image [image]

Please help me guys.

Comment: My question is how to show google map in background

Comment: All you need to do is set the Google Map up inside a 100% div with a lower z-index than anything you wish to display above it. You may also wish to disable scroll zoom, otherwise site navigation may be irritating. There are many examples a Google search away.

Comment: It is really easy. Here is the tutorial http://www.spambox.in/how-to-set-google-maps-as-background-for-webpage/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might help you.

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map (Google Developers are showing how to add a google map to your website)

and...

http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2013/05/07/use-a-google-map-as-the-background-of-your-webpage/

(the other link shows how to use it as a background)

Edit...the whole code should look like this: This is from Google Developers and they explain how to put it in your website.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code where you can set the Google Map as background.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/test/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBNLDwRv4ItlTJRouExNPpJokdKK859yDk">
</script>
<script src="/test/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
<h1>OMG, this is ON TOP OF THE MAP!</h1>
</div>

<div id='map-canvas'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

+javascript ofc...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as you are a new user, but remember that we do not expect link only answers, as if the links are dead, your answer won't be useful anymore :)

Comment: Could you please put the important parts of the links in the answer, as link-only answers aren't good here, as they can break.

Comment: and yes, the links are dead

Comment: just checked them...they are still holding on :)

Answer (score -6):

**No** you can't set Google Maps as background image, because it is like a canvas.

One possibility is you can position other elements, on the Google Maps with ***absolute positioning***.